# how to get tick mark for question number in quiz for correct answer i green colour and cross mark for wrong answer with red colour . new to angular

Tags: css, angular

here is my html code . all questions comming from data base and displaying depends on question number.

```
  <h4>{{indexOfelement+1}}</h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

in css i should display questions like below.
[image: my output should be this]
how can i acheive this. question have right answer from data base. like below.
question.questionAnswer. how can i write logic to display if question number is correct, it should display in green colour with tick mark , if wrong it should display red with cross mark.
i have to write a logic to get question number with colours. we have list reportAllQuestionDisplay have all question and with answers from API.

Comment: Add class based on selected option, compare selected option with right answer and return value of true or false, ngClass will help you. To add icon based on value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never show the shape of the return data from the API, so I am going to create the shape, and supply the mock data.

I will try to explain what I did in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u7zuvw):

In the `app.component.ts` file, I have a mock data.

```
// Mock backend data.
  public resultViewModels: ResultViewModel[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      question: 'How are you?',
      answer: 'I am great!',
      isCorrect: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: 'Where are you?',
      answer: 'Somewhere',
      isCorrect: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      question: 'What day is today?',
      answer: 'No sure',
      isCorrect: false,
    },
  ];
```

Your API will return a different shape, so you will need to make some changes. The `id` property is used as the answer number on the UI. The `isCorrect` property to show the Green vs. Red. It is also used to show/hide the icon.

In the `app.component.html`

```
<div class="result-grid">
  <div
    *ngFor="let result of resultViewModels"
    class="result"
    [class.correct]="result.isCorrect"
    [class.incorrect]="!result.isCorrect"
  >
    <span>{{ result.id }}</span>
    <!-- Replace these with icon of your choice -->
    <span *ngIf="result.isCorrect">Check</span>
    <span *ngIf="!result.isCorrect">Cross</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, we do two things:

1. `[class.correct]`.
2. `*ngIf="result.correct"`

The 1st one tells Angular to add a class called "correct" to the div if the `result.isCorrect` is true.

The 2nd one tells Angular to show the "Check" icon if the `result.correct` is true. And hide when `result.correct` is false.

Here is the `app.component.css`

```
.result-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 50px));
  gap: 16px;
}

.result {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

/*
  used when [class.correct]="true"
*/
.result.correct {
  background-color: green;
}

/*
  used when [class.incorrect]="true"
*/
.result.incorrect {
  background-color: red;
}
```